# How do I access a variable from another function in a seperate function?

Tags: python, tkinter

as you can see I am trying to access the text_box variable from the add_student function to the see_record function. (this is not the full code). Any Help would be appreciated

```
def add_student(self):
    self.root = tk.Tk()
    self.root.title("ADD STUDENT")
    self.root.geometry("600x400")
    self.root.configure(bg="white")
    self.root.resizable(False, False)

    def save():
        self.root.destroy()
        save_root = tk.Tk()
        save_root.resizable(False, False)

        saved = tk.Label(save_root, text="THE STUDENT HAS BEEN SAVED!", font="Consoles, 16").pack()

        save_root.mainloop()

    header = tk.Label(self.root, text="STUDENT NAME AND AGE GO HERE", font="Consoles, 17").pack()
    # text_box variable
    text_box = tk.Entry(self.root, width=60, font="Consoles, 15")
    text_box.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
    save = tk.Button(self.root, text="SAVE", width=30, height=4, command=save).pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    self.root.mainloop()

def see_record(self):
    record_root = tk.Tk()
    record_root.title("STUDENT RECORDS")
    record_root.geometry("600x400")
    record_root.configure(bg="white")

    scroll = tk.Scrollbar(record_root).pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    
    # where I am trying to access the text_box variable
    record_label = tk.Label(record_root, text=self.add_student.text_box.get(), font="Consoles, 16")
    record_label.pack()

    record_root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `Entry` is missing a "Tcl" variable, that all input is going to be stored in , create `my_var = tk.StringVar()` in some global name space, and specify for `Entry` to use `my_var` by `tk.Entry(...,textvariable = my_var)`. Then to read its contents use `my_var.get()`, to pre-set text inside `Entry` use `my_var.set("sample text")`

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have that all set but the label wont appear in the window

Comment: I can't help much with the partial code. As a "diagnostic" step, try specifying `background = blue` and `width = 10` when creating the `Label`, just to see where it show up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this with self.text_box.

Comment: I get error "Window object has no attribute "text_box"

Comment: ah, my fault.. u have to create new variable:
`self.text_box_var = tk.StringVar()`
and use it in the tk.Entry:
`text_box = tk.Entry(self.root, width=60, font="Consoles, 15", textvariable=self.text_box_var)`
when you need to return string from this variable use .get()
`record_label = tk.Label(record_root, text=self.text_box_var.get(), font="Consoles, 16")`